# Segmentation fault em C: Estrutura de Adjacência representando grafo

Tags: c, lógica, grafo

Preciso criar um programa para ler um grafo e representar em uma estrutura de adjacência, entretanto, meu compilador está acusando *segmentation fault* e não consigo descobrir o que pode estar causando isso. Pode me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *ent;
FILE *saida;
int V, E;
int **matriz;
struct adj{
    int w, v;
    struct adj *prox;
};
typedef
struct adj grafo;
grafo **G;

void Estrutura (int V);
void M_Adj (int **matriz, int V);
void ZerarMatriz (int **matriz);
void printMatriz (int **matriz, int V);
void printEstrutura (grafo **G, int V);

int main()//(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    //declarações e abertura de arquivos
    ent = fopen("ent.txt", "r");
    saida = fopen("sai.txt", "w");

    //ler arquivo de entrada e declarações
    int i,v, w, Vi;
    fscanf(ent, "%d %d", &V, &E);

    //alocar matriz
    matriz = malloc(V * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
        matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(V * sizeof(int));

    //alocar vetor cabeça do grafo
    G = (grafo **) malloc(sizeof(V*sizeof(grafo)));

    //int matriz[V][V];
    fprintf (saida, "Arquivo de entrada \n \n");
    fprintf(saida, "%d %d \n", V, E);
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        fscanf(ent, "%d", &v);
        fprintf(saida, "%d ", v);
        fscanf(ent, "%d", &w);
        if (w != 0) fscanf(ent, "%d", &Vi);
        while (w != 0){
        fprintf(saida,"%d %d ", w, Vi);
        fscanf(ent, "%d", &w);
        if (w != 0) fscanf(ent, "%d", &Vi);
    }
    fprintf(saida, "\n");
    }
    ZerarMatriz(matriz);
    M_Adj(matriz, V);
    Estrutura(V);
    fclose(ent);
    fclose(saida);
    free(matriz);
    return 0;
}

void Estrutura (int V){
    ent = fopen("ent.txt", "r");
    int i, Vi, w, v, VV, EE;
    fscanf(ent, "%d", &VV);
    fscanf(ent, "%d", &EE);
    printf("Tam: %d %d \n", VV, EE);
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
        (G[i]->prox) = NULL; -- O ERRO É ACUSADO AQUI
    struct adj *aux = malloc(sizeof(struct adj));
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        fscanf(ent, "%d %d", &Vi, &w);
        printf("\n %d %d \n", Vi,w);
        while (w != 0){
            fscanf(ent, "%d", &v);
            aux->prox = NULL;
            aux->v = v;
            aux->w = w;
            if (&(G[i]->prox) == NULL){  -- SE EU NÃO COLOCAR O & COMERCIAL TAMBÉM É ACUSADO AQUI
                G[i]->prox = aux;}
            else
            {
                grafo *aux2 = G[i];
                while(&(aux2->prox) != NULL) -- SE EU NÃO COLOCAR O & COMERCIAL TAMBÉM É ACUSADO AQUI
                    aux2 = (grafo *) (aux2->prox); -- ISSO TAMBÉM NÃO PARECE FUNCIONAR
                (aux2->prox) = aux;
                aux2 = NULL;
            }
            fscanf(ent, "%d", &w);
        }
    }
    aux = NULL;
    fprintf(saida," \n Estrutura de Adjacência: \n");
    printEstrutura(G, V);
}
```

Eu sei que está um pouco redundante, mas é para fins didáticos. Obrigado.

------------------------------------ Atualização ----------------------------

Victor, muito obrigado pela resposta mas mesmo com essas alterações ainda restaram alguns problemas, por isso, resolvi adicionar os novos vértices no inicio da lista, com as alterações o código ficou assim:

```
void Estrutura (int V){
    ent = fopen("ent.txt", "r");
    int i, Vi, w, v, VV, EE;
    fscanf(ent, "%d", &VV);
    fscanf(ent, "%d", &EE);
    printf("Tam: %d %d \n", VV, EE);
    struct adj *aux = malloc(sizeof(struct adj));
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        fscanf(ent, "%d %d", &Vi, &w);
        printf("\n %d %d ", Vi,w);
        while (w != 0){
            fscanf(ent, "%d", &v);
            printf(" %d %d ", w, v);
            aux->prox = NULL;
            aux->v = v;
            aux->w = w;
            if (G[i] == NULL){
                G[i] = aux;
            }
            else{
                aux->prox = G[i];
                G[i] = aux;
            }
            fscanf(ent, "%d", &w);
        }
    }
    aux = NULL;
    printEstrutura(G, V);
}

void printEstrutura (grafo **G, int V){
    int i;
    struct adj *aux;
    fprintf(saida, "/n PRINTANDO ESTRUTURA :DDDDD");
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        aux = G[i];
        while (aux != NULL){
             fprintf(saida, "%d %d", aux->w, aux->v);
             aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }
}
```

Mas com as alterações, meu código fica em loop na função print. Estou há tempos trabalhando direito e isso está atrapalhando bastante meu rendimento, vou dormir um pouco pra evitar deslizes como o últimos. Obrigado.

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o seu principal problema está aqui:

```
G = (grafo **) malloc(sizeof(V*sizeof(grafo)));
```

Você errou os parênteses! E como resultado vai alocar uma quantidade de memória bem menor que a que deveria, o que vai causar falha de segmentação quando você acessar o ponteiro alguma posição além da que foi alocada.

O que você queria é isso daqui:

```
G = (grafo **) malloc(V * sizeof(grafo*));
```

No entanto, você deve ter sempre em mente que isso vai criar um array de ponteiros para adjacências e não um array de adjacências.

**Atenção, neste momento esta região da memória conterá lixo, o que significa que você terá um array de ponteiros inválidos.** Então, é uma boa ideia inicializar o array:

```
G = (grafo **) malloc(V * sizeof(grafo*));
for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    G[i] = NULL;
}
```

Mais para frente, isso vai dar errado:

```
for (i = 0; i < V; i++)
    (G[i]->prox) = NULL; // O ERRO É ACUSADO AQUI
```

Pois `G[i]` é nulo! E se você não tiver colocado aquele laço `for` que eu sugeri antes, então será ainda pior, pois `G[i]` será um ponteiro preenchido com lixo. A solução é simplesmente retirar este laço do programa, você não precisa dele.

No laço `for` grande da função `Estrutura`, você não define nada em nenhuma das posições do array `G`. Portanto sempre que você tentar acessar `G[i]`, alguma coisa ruim vai acontecer. Em algum lugar você deveria fazer isso:

```
G[i] = alguma_coisa;
```

Por fim, isso não é o que você quer:

```
if (&(G[i]->prox) == NULL)
...
while(&(aux2->prox) != NULL)
```

Pois, se `G[i]` for um ponteiro válido, então `&(G[i]->prox)` nunca vai ser nulo, pois o ponteiro sempre terá um endereço neste caso. E se `G[i]` for um ponteiro inválido, isso vai dar falha de segmentação. O mesmo se aplica para `aux2`. Portanto, com o `&`, ou ocorre uma falha de segmentação, ou então o `if` nunca vai entrar e o `while` nunca vai sair.

O que você quer não é saber se o endereço do ponteiro é nulo e sim se o próprio ponteiro é nulo. Então, retire o `&`.

Aliás, o endereço de qualquer variável no programa nunca vai ser nulo, uma vez que qualquer variável em que você pode usar o operador de endereço existe, e se ela existe, então ela está em algum endereço em algum lugar de memória. Se não existir, você vai ter uma falha de segmentação ao tentar acessar uma variável que não existe. Por isso, o operador `&` nunca vai te dar nulo como resposta*.

*: <sup><sub>Exceto se você estiver programando alguma parte crítica do kernel do sistema operacional ou da BIOS que precise manipular algum valor na posição zero da memória, o que provavelmente você nunca vai fazer.</sub></sup>

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Não vejo nada de errado no código da sua atualização. Certifique-se que o array `G` foi devidamente inicializado com `NULL` em todas as posições. Se não for isso, sugiro colocar alguns `printf` sempre que adicionar alguma adjacência ao grafo e então tentar encontrar aonde e como ele pode gerar alguma coisa incorreta no grafo que faça o `printEstrutura` entrar em loop infinito.

Além disso, no seu novo código dá para simplificar isso:

```
        aux->prox = NULL;
        aux->v = v;
        aux->w = w;
        if (G[i] == NULL){
            G[i] = aux;
        }
        else{
            aux->prox = G[i];
            G[i] = aux;
        }
```

E transformar nisso:

```
        aux->prox = G[i];
        aux->v = v;
        aux->w = w;
        G[i] = aux;
```

Answer (score 1):

Victor, eu fui meio bobo ao desenvolver o código, sempre que alterava o aux ele ainda estava apontando para mesma posição, logo gerava o loop infinito no print. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

A versão corrigida ficou assim:

```
for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
    fscanf(ent, "%d %d", &Vi, &w);
    printf("\n %d ", Vi,w);
    while (w != 0){
        aux = malloc(sizeof(struct adj));
        fscanf(ent, "%d ", &v);
        aux->v = v;
        aux->w = w;
        printf("%d %d ", aux->w, aux->v);
        aux->prox = G[Vi];
        G[Vi] = aux;
        fscanf(ent, "%d", &w);
        aux = NULL;
    }
}
```